# Pointwise boundedness is uniform for a sequence of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f \in C^\infty ([a, b])$ be an infinitely differentiable function defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$ with the following property: for any $x \in [a, b]$ the sequence $|f^{(n)}(x)|$ is bounded, i.e.:

$$ \forall x \in [a, b] \;\; \exists C_x \in \mathbb R \;\; \forall n \geq 0 \;\; |f^{(n)}(x)| \leq C_x $$

Prove that there is a constant $C$ such that $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq C$ for all $n \geq 0$ and $x \in [a, b]$.

Clarification: the derivatives are defined on *closed* intervals by taking one-side limits.

---

My ideas:

- $C_x$ is actually a function if we set:
  $$ C_x := \sup_{n \geq 0} |f^{(n)}(x)| $$
- The task is to prove that this function is bounded on $[a, b]$. By contradiction?
- Suppose $C_x$ is unbounded. Then there is a sequence $(n_k, x_k)$ such that
  $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} |f^{(n_k)}(x_k)| = \infty $$
- $n_k$ cannot be bounded since otherwise there would be infinitely many pairs $(n_0, x_k)$ for some $n_0$. The limit above would still be infinity for that subsequence, but for a *fixed* function $f^{(n_0)}$ that is impossible since it is a continuous function defined on a closed interval.
- The sequence $(n_k, x_k)$ can be chosen in such way that:

  - $n_k$ are strictly increasing
  - $x_k$ converge to some $x_0 \in [a, b]$

However, I have no idea how to use this sequence. Any advice? What direction should I look in?

Comment: Where did you read this property ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo, nowhere. This is a homework assignment which was announced without any reference.

Comment: What theorems did you cover about sequences of functions ?

Comment: @G.T.R, pointwise convergence, uniform convergence. Facts that properties like continuity and differentiability carry to the uniform limit, but not to the pointwise limit. That's pretty much it, but I assume that this assignment implies extra research. I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: Okay. Do you know Baire theorem?

Comment: @G.T.R, now I do. Although I don't see how it could be possibly related to this problem.

Comment: This gives a partial answer http://mathb.in/16859

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you get a correction for this very interesting question ?

Comment: @G.T.R, in a sense. There were actually two problems of this sort, this one being the latter. The former problem's statement was «prove that if an infinitely differentiable function $f$ defined on a closed segment $[a,b]$ satisfies $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ at every $x$ for some $n$ then it is a polynomial». That problem can be attacked with Baire theorem in a fairly straightforward way. As for the latter problem, I was told that there is a completely crazy but elementary solution and that it would be pretty shocking if I discovered it. Of course I did not mention the Pringsheim-Boas theorem.

Answer (score 6):

You can get your result by using a nice theorem sometimes called the "Pringsheim-Boas theorem". This theorem was stated by Pringsheim in 1934 but there was a gap in the proof, and Boas gave a correct proof in 1935.

To state this theorem, one needs to explain (or recall) what an *analytic* function of a real variable is. A function $f\in\mathcal C^\infty([a,b])$ is said to be analytic if for any $s\in [a,b]$, one can find an open interval $I_s$ with center $s$ such that $f(x)= \sum_0^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(s)}{k!}\, (x-s)^k$ on $I_s\cap [a,b]$.

Note that the definition of analyticity is local: the above power series may not converge to $f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, even if it is convergent for all $x\in [a,b]$.

The Pringsheim-Boas theorem reads as follows. Let $f$ be a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function on $[a,b]$. For each $s\in [a,b]$, denote by $\rho(s)$ the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum \frac{f^{(k)}(s)}{k!}\, (x-s)^k$. If there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\forall s\in [a,b]\;:\; \rho(s)\geq \delta$, then $f$ is *analytic* on $[a,b]$.

The prooof of this theorem is not at all trivial, and does use the Baire category theorem. Here is a link to Boas' paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-04/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5.pdf

Let us see how the Pringsheim-Boas theorem can be used to get what you want.

Your assumption on $f$ clearly implies that $\rho(s)=\infty$ for every $x\in [a,b]$; so $f$ is analytic on $[a,b]$. Let $s_0$ be any point of $(a,b)$, for example $s_0=\frac{a+b}2\cdot$ let $f_0$ be the function defined on $\mathbb R$ by $$f_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(s_0)}{k!}\, (x-s_0)^k\, . $$

Being the sum of a convergent power series, this function is analytic on $\mathbb R$ (this is one of the basic results of the theory of analytic functions). Moreover, $f_0$ agrees with $f$ on a neighbourhood of $s_0$. Since $f_0$ and $f$ are both analytic, it follows (by the so-called *identity principle* for analytic functions) that $f_0=f$ on $[a,b]$. So we have
$$\forall x\in [a,b]\; :\; f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(s_0)}{k!}\, (x-s_0)^{k}\, . $$
By the standard theory of power series, you can differentiate under the $\Sigma$. This gives for all $n\geq 0$:
\begin{eqnarray}f^{(n)}(x)&=&\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{k(k-1)\cdots (k-n+1)}{k!}f^{(k)}(s_0)\, (x-s_0)^{k-n}\\
&=&\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(s_0)}{(k-n)!}\,(x-s_0)^{k-n} .
\end{eqnarray}
Now, by assumption there is a constant $C_0=C_{s_0}$ such that $\vert f^{(k)}(s_0)\vert\leq C_0$ for all $k\geq 0$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray}\forall x\in [a,b]\;\forall n\;:\; \vert f^{(n)}(x)\vert&\leq& C_0\, \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{(x-s_0)^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}\\
&=& C_0\, e^{x-s_0}\\
&\leq& C_0e^{b-a}\, .
\end{eqnarray}
Since $C:=C_0e^{b-a}$ is independent of $x$ and $n$, this concludes the proof.

Comment: Can you explain why "Your assumption on $f$ clearly implies that $\rho(s)=\infty$ for every $x\in [a,b]$" ?

Comment: The radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{z^k}{k!}$ is $\infty$; so if $\vert f^{(k)}(s)\vert\leq C_s$ for all $k$, then the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ at $s$ is also $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this. +1

Comment: Very nice answer. In fact we can prove this exercise with only 'elementary' (without Pringsheim-Boas theorem)  method but is not trivial too. If you are interested look at p.169 in Makarov's Selected Problems in Real Analysis.

Comment: @Krokop Thanks for the reference; I'll have a look at Makarov.